# How to reset a variable in Flume's custom sink class for every batch

Tags: java, flume

I have a flume process that reads data from file on a spooldir & loads the data into MySQL database. There will be multiple types of files that can be processed by the same flume process.

I have created a custom sink java class (extending AbstractSink), that updates a local variable (sInterfaceType) after an initial/first read to decide the data format in the file. 
I have to reset it once the file processing completes, so that it has to start with identifying the next batch/interface file.

I tried to do in stop() but it doesn't help. Did anybody do this?

My sink class looks like this:

```
public class MyFlumeSink2 extends AbstractSink implements Configurable {

 private String sInterfaceType; //tells file format of current load

 public MyFlumeSink2() {
  //my initialization of variables
 }

 public void configure(Context context) {
  //read context variables
 }

 public void start() {
  //create db connection
 }

 @Override
 public void stop() {
  //destroy connection
  sInterfaceType = ""; //This doesn't help me
  super.stop();
 }

 public Status process() throws EventDeliveryException {
   Channel channel = getChannel();
   Transaction transaction = channel.getTransaction();

   if((sInterfaceType=="" || sInterfaceType==null))
   {
    //Read first line & set sInterfaceType
   }else
     //Insert data in MySQL

   transaction.commit();
 }
}
```

Comment: How do you detect (at sink level) a file has been completly processed?

Comment: I was thinking that stop() method is called after completing one batch or a file. But it looks like that is not the case. So I don't know the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to manually decide which event it is, there is no specialized method called for every new file.

I revised my code to read the event line & set InterfaceType based on first element. My code looks like this:

```
public Status process() throws EventDeliveryException {
        //....other code...

            sEvtBody = new String(event.getBody());
            sFields = sEvtBody.split(",");

            //check first field to know record type
            enumRec = RecordType.valueOf( checkRecordType(sFields[0].toUpperCase()) );
            switch(enumRec)
            {
                case CUST_ID:
                    sInterfaceType = "T_CUST";
                    bHeader = true;
                    break;
                case TXN_ID:
                    sInterfaceType = "T_CUST_TXNS";
                    bHeader = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    bHeader = false;
            }
            //insert if not header
            if(!bHeader)
            {

                if(sInterfaceType == "T_CUST")
                {
                    if(sFields.length == 14)
                        this.bInsertStatus = daoClass.insertHeader(sFields);
                    else
                        throw new Exception("INCORRECT_COLUMN_COUNT");
                }else if(sInterfaceType == "T_CUST_TXNS")
                {
                    if(sFields.length == 10)
                        this.bInsertStatus = daoClass.insertData(sFields);
                    else
                        throw new Exception("INCORRECT_COLUMN_COUNT");
                }

                //if(!bInsertStatus)
                //  logTransaction(sFields);
            }
            //....Other code....
```